# Symfony command triggered by crontab is not closing

Tags: php, symfony, cron, cron-task

We have two symfony commands in our project: one that is being triggered by the crontab and other that is triggered by the first one (so that emails are being sent in batches), like this:

The problem is that the process triggered by crontab are never closing, they are keep running on the server until the RAM memory is full (crons are being triggered every two hours), even that the code finish running (all emails are being sent).

We've tried adding a timeout option in crontab but this doesn't seems to work either.

In crontab, the command is:

```
0  */2  *  *  * root /usr/bin/timeout 5400 /path/to/symfony/console mycron:trigger
```

And this is the list of processes on the server (as you can see, even if the timeout should be 5400s, processes are alive for over 17h):

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12231 apache    20   0  754m 414m 9544 S  0.0  5.6  17:11.74 php-fpm 
12224 apache    20   0  754m 414m 9588 S  0.0  5.6  18:00.81 php-fpm
12267 apache    20   0  725m 385m 9580 S  0.0  5.3  14:30.35 php-fpm
12300 apache    20   0  725m 384m 9536 S  0.0  5.2  15:42.68 php-fpm
12338 apache    20   0  717m 377m 9556 S  0.0  5.1  14:11.93 php-fpm
```

Any ideas would be really appeciated

Comment: Did you try with a exit?

Comment: Yeah, `exit` is there

Comment: would be hard without seeing the command code at least